# Set matrix elements that are in another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `Path` that contains points (x,y) and it's 100*2 in size.I also have another matrix `Image` that is 500*500.
I want to set all the pointsin `Image`that exist in `Path` to zero
I tried to use

```
 arrayfun(@(x) find(segmentedimage==x),path,'UniformOutput',false)
```

and it returned 100x2 cell but i dont know what to do after that.
I guess i have to do something like

```
segmentedimage(path(:,:))=0;
```

Can any one tell me how to set all points to 0 without loops.

Comment: Use `sub2ind` on `Path` and then index into `Image` to set them to zeros. I would suggest to read the documentation on [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) as it's a very handy tool when dealing with matrices.

Comment: Nothing matches the feeling of tasting success when trying it out yourself, right!? :)

Comment: You may post what worked for you as an answer and accept it. Unanswered questions don't look *good* on SO, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting help, I used [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert the points location into indices

```
segmentedimage(sub2ind(size(segmentedimage),path(:,1),path(:,2)))=0;
```